# Bash - How to make sure folder is removed?

Tags: bash, shell, rm

I'm very new to bash scripting so I have a very little question about it. I have a system that creates a cache folders everyday from 00:00 to 00:00, what I want to do is;

1. Remove yesterdays folder (removing this folder takes about 2-3
   mins)
2. Make sure its removed
3. Clear mod_pagespeed's cache.

What I did so far is; (code edited thanks to @Cyrus)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

LOG_FILE=/var/log/pagespeed/fixer.log
dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');

WORKING_DIR='somepath/folder_name';

if [ -d "$WORKING_DIR" ]; then rm -Rf $WORKING_DIR; fi


if touch "$(grep "^ *ModPagespeedFileCachePath" /etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf | awk ' { print $2; } ' | sed 's/"//g')/cache.flush"; then
        exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE})
        exec 2> >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} >&2)
        echo "Cache_Fixed: $dt"
        exit 0
else
    echo "Fail.."
fi
```

But I believe this code may fail sometimes, I don't know why. What method should I follow to improve my script to make sure folder is removed completely to execute clean cache command?

Thanks in advance!

***Edit***

Crontab

```
05 00 * * * /.../MPGS_Fixer/fixer.sh
```

Comment: Multiple problems. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you, fixed all but cant fix ; `grep "^ *ModPagespeedFileCachePath" /etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf | awk ' { print $2; } ' | sed 's/"//g'/cache.flush;`. Also, If I fix this line also, will my script work as intended or should I add more if statements to check anything else?